# Bootstrap Server Status Parsing Errors

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have got this code together for a server status (Minecraft, to be more specific) using php code I found, and bootstrap. I am kind of new to php, so I don't know how to fix this error. Every time I go to view the webpage I put the code on, it gives me this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'progress' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in  /home/u7335206/public_html/mc-vr.com/status.php on line 10
```

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mc-vr.com/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mc-vr.com/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://mc-vr.com/js/bootstrap.css">
<script src="http://mc-vr.com/js/bootstrap.css">
<?php
// Script by Akensai

if (!$socket = @fsockopen("192.99.14.177:25578", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
echo "<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"       aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
<span class="sr-only">100% Complete (danger)</span>
</div>
</div>";
}
else 
{
echo "<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"    aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
<span class="sr-only">100% Complete (success)</span>
</div>
</div>";


fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

Could any of you please give me insight into what is wrong, and what I need to fix? If so, that would be great.

Comment: replace the " by ' in the 2 echo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not escaping out your quotes, in

`echo "<div class="progress progress-striped active">`

You're essentially ending the string at `"<div class="` and then PHP sees a bunch of stuff after that and doesn't know what to make of it.

My suggestion, either use single quotes inside of your PHP string, or escape your quotes with a backslash.

Single quotes: `echo "<div class='progress progress-striped active'>";`

Escape: `echo "<div class=\"progress progress-striped active\">";`

This is a common issue when outputting HTML with PHP.  I'd look at the PHP documentation, and specifically heredoc and nowdoc, they can make the pain of escaping quotes, or replacing all yours quotes much less:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php